# List<List<Integer>> ArrayList initialization does not work with new operator Java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, initialization, variable-assignment

I have been struggling on this problem for two days. This problem comes from some problem I am doing. Basically, when I use

```
List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>(result);
```

to create a new ArrayList copy of result, the result will change when I try to change temp within an advanced for loop. For example,

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(new ArrayList<>());
List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>(result);
int j = 0;
for (List<Integer> list: temp) {
    list.add(x[j]);
    j ++;
}
```

I did nothing to the result inside the loop but the result ends up with [[1]], which is the same as temp.

Why is this happening? Thanks a lot.

Update: thank everybody for answering my question. I learn the shallow copy was the reason. However, I still run into a similar problem. The result is updated while I try to change the temp in the following code:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(new ArrayList<>());
List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Integer> list: result) {
    list.add(10000);
    temp.add(new ArrayList(list));
}
```

I do not know why the result turns out to be [[10000]] as well as the temp. Is there anything wrong with the add method like temp.add(new ArrayList(list))?

Comment: Also, what does the x do in front of the [j]?

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(result)` only does a shallow copy of `result`, i.e. it copies the "outer" list, but not its elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the `List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>(result);` statement copies only the top-level list. It will be the new list that contains references to the original items (aka sublists) from the original `result`.

You can fix this with a deep copy:

```
List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>(); // empty list
for (List<Integer> sublist : result) {
    temp.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(result)); // copying a sublist and adding that
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, if you got time, could you please have a further look at my new similar problem? I updated the problem in the end of my post.

Answer (score 1):

This is not surprising because you have only one list to iterate upon. If you add a second list you will see a second digit coming in.

```
int[] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}; 

    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new ArrayList());
result.add(new ArrayList());
    List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<>(result);
    for (Integer xx: x) {
        result.add(new ArrayList(xx));
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

If you try this code it will display you:

```
[[1],[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp = new ArrayList<>(result)` only does a shallow copy of `result`, i.e. it copies the "outer" list, but not its elements.

`temp.get(0) == result.get(0)` - and I don't mean `equals` - they are exactly the same instance.

As such, anything you add to `temp.get(0)` will also appear in `result.get(0)`.

Comment: Hi Sir, if you got time, could you please have a further look at my new similar problem? I updated the problem in the end of my post.